# how to call phtml file of another folder inside phtml file of another folder in magento 2

Tags: magento2, phtml

I have a.phtml file in one folder in my theme folder and b.phtml in another folder now i want to call inside one phtml file to another b.phtml file

Comment: Please, explain more details about your phtml files. These files are in different modules?

Comment: No i have two folder in my theme folder both have a phtml file now i want to call one phtml file inside one

Comment: i use this but this work within same folder                                                                      <?php include($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Customer::newcustomer.phtml')) ?>

Comment: You can provide the folder structure?

Comment: ITT a lot of ppl that don't know `getChildHtml()`

Answer (score 2):

You can call any template file inside any template file using below line

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate('Company_Module::test.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a .phtml file use:

`<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Theme::html/example.phtml')) ?>`

`Magento_Theme::html/example.phtml` corresponds to the file at: `<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/example.phtml`

So to get a file from another module, say the catalog module, you can use:
`<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::example.phtml')) ?>`

`Magento_Catalog::example.phtml` corresponds to the file at:
`<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/example.phtml`

Comment: I use this but it didn't work basically i want to call view.phtml file that inside Magento_LayeredNavigation folder and i want to call  in my product list.phtml both module are different

Comment: Yes it work but here i want to call three file within one statement because all three are connected how to call this three file i can not call one by one

Comment: I see. Is there any reason why you can't call the blocks in xml instead? It's better practice.